# Adding jQuery slideToggle() to oncliked event on anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched the whole web and I didn't manage to find a solution to my problem. I have some anchor links, in a fixed header, like this:

```
 <ul>
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Tab1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#s1">link1</a>
       <a href="#s2">link2</a>
    </div>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Tab2</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#s3">link3</a>
      <a href="#s4">link4</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
 <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Tab3</a>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#s5">link5</a>
  <a href="#s6">link6</a>
  <a href="#s7">link7</a>
 </div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Tab4</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#s8">link8</a>
    <a href="#s9">link9</a>
    <a href="#s0">link10</a>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

In my application, all these sections are hidden (`.content{display:none;}`, with `content` as the class of the tables). For example:

```
<div class="content">   
  <p>I am a section.</p>
     <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
         <table class="normal" id="s1">*data*</table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Now, I'd like to `slideToggle()` the selected table (with the anchor link) in order to show it, and hide any previously "slided" table. I've tried a lot of jQuery codes, but none worked. What event/function may I have to add to onclick event of these anchor links?

Comment: First thing first, you have an invalid markup.

Comment: where is .content item? where is tables?

Comment: Edited the question. Hope things are clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite simply in jQuery by using seperate counts of `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` instead of `slideToggle()`.

I've replicated your environment in a fiddle and dropped the code in, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wo9n0yLt/

The code is below:

```js
$('.menu > li > a').click(function() {
  var tab = $(this).attr('href');
  $('table').each(function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
  });
  $(tab).slideDown();
});
```

```css
table {
  display: none;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  My Menu Toggler
</h2>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#tab1">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<table id="tab1">
  <tr>
    <td>TABLE 1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="tab2">
  <tr>
    <td>TABLE 2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="tab3">
  <tr>
    <td>TABLE 3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is surely helpful. Thanks. What if i have to apply this script to a div section?

Comment: Good to know :) Yeah that would be fine, as long as the `div` section has the corresponding `id` of the menu item. i.e: `<div id="tab3">....` Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helps :)

Comment: I modified your fiddle, it seems to not be working with divs, but surely it is my fault. I will keep trying!

Comment: @JimmyPage Remember that you will have to modify both the rules in CSS and in the jQuery if you change to `div`'s - see updated fiddle using `div`'s    https://jsfiddle.net/wo9n0yLt/1/

Comment: I solved the issue this way: https://jsfiddle.net/2xzq913L/ . Anyway, in my application it still does not work. I think it is because of my <ul> structure

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<a id="tab1" onclick="toggleTable();" href="#">Link</a>
```

JavaScript

```
function toggleTable() {
     $('#YourTableID').toggle('slow');
     $('#AlreadyOpenedTableID').hide();
}
```

Comment: With this i cannot hide already opened tables. Anyway, i should write as many functions as the number of the tables...

Comment: Hide that table that you want to hide below that